# SQLite: How to find two sum values as well as difference between them?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Say I have a table with a bunch of currency exchange pairs. It has 4 columns:

`CURR_BOUGHT | AMT_BOUGHT | CURR_SOLD | AMT_SOLD`

So say we have 10 GBP and we exchange it for 13.33 USD, the row would be populated with:

`USD | 13.33 | GBP | 10`

We have a whole bunch of these transactions in various currency pairs. Now say I want to find out the total sum of USD I've bought over all transactions, as well as the total sum of USD I've sold over all transactions, and also the difference between the two? Is it possible to run a query that will print these 3 numbers?

This rather messy query will print the 3 numbers in separate rows. I am trying to get it so that it prints the 3 numbers in separate columns on the same single row.

`SELECT SUM(AMT_BOUGHT) FROM TRADES WHERE (CURR_BOUGHT = 'USD') UNION
SELECT SUM(AMT_SOLD) FROM TRADES WHERE (CURR_SOLD = 'USD') UNION
SELECT (SELECT SUM(AMT_BOUGHT) FROM TRADES WHERE (CURR_BOUGHT = 'USD')) - (SELECT SUM(AMT_SOLD) FROM TRADES WHERE (CURR_SOLD = 'USD')) FROM TRADES;`

Comment: Yes. It is possible, and your title already contains information that will allow you to make an effort to do so. When you have, and you run into difficulties, you can then come back here and explain the problem you're having, include the SQL you've written making that effort, and ask a specific question related to that SQL. Good luck.

Comment: I'm a bit new here and didn't realise that I should have included my previous effort. I thought it might just cloud the issue, but I have now included it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you use above with the unions give you one result for each rows (that's what union does - adds separate groups of rows together). To make it so it is all one query, get rid of the unions and use commas, making each of the individual queries a subquery.

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(AMT_BOUGHT) FROM TRADES WHERE (CURR_BOUGHT = 'USD')) AS AMT_BOUGHT, 
    (SELECT SUM(AMT_SOLD) FROM TRADES WHERE (CURR_SOLD = 'USD')) AS AMT_SOLD,
    (SELECT SUM(AMT_BOUGHT) FROM TRADES WHERE (CURR_BOUGHT = 'USD')) - (SELECT SUM(AMT_SOLD) FROM TRADES WHERE (CURR_SOLD = 'USD')) FROM TRADES AS DIFF;
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I also had to change to 'SELECT DISTINCT ...' otherwise it was returning multiple rows with the same answer (as many rows as I had USD trades). I still feel like my query is not so clean and doing a bit of hackery to get there, but the answers are correct so that's all that matters, right :P

Comment: Ah, I didn't look at that part.  You don't need the distinct if you get rid of the FROM TRADES at the end. It is currently saying that you should do all the calculations for each row in trades, which is redundant.